# FDDB evaluation code

Tags: opencv, face-detection, evaluation, dlib, evaluate

I'm studying opencv and dlib, for a face detector to use on a university project, and I'm really new at this whole thing of machine learning and computer vision. How can I use the evaluation code from [FDDB](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/fddb/results.html) to evaluate my code for face detection? I'm using dlib's CNN method for detecting faces from images.

```
import cv2
import dlib

image = cv2.imread('..\\pessoas\\beatles.jpg')

detector = dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1("..\\mmods\\mmod_human_face_detector.dat")
detectedFaces = detector(image)

for face in detectedFaces:
    l, t, r, b, c = (int(face.rect.left()), int(face.rect.top()), int(face.rect.right()), int(face.rect.bottom()),
                 face.confidence)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (l, t), (r, b), (255, 0, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("CNN Detector", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As you can see the code is pretty simple, but I have to calculate precision, recall, and F1-score to plot the ROC curves and I'm don't know yet how to do it, the readme on the project's [github](https://github.com/npinto/fddb-evaluation) doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to me in ubuntu16, I have to done it by the following steps:

1. Download the fddb original images dataset which you detect face and get detection result.You can download it [here](http://tamaraberg.com/faceDataset/originalPics.tar.gz).Here is my directory:
   [image]
2. Join all the images file path to a txt file , and join all the fddb annotations to a txt file.
   You can download all the files [here](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/fddb/FDDB-folds.tgz)

[image]

As to me I move all the `FDDB-FOLD-%d.txt` to the directory `all_file_path`, and then join them to one file by `cat * > filePath.txt`

[image]

Join all the `FDDB-fold-%d-ellipseList.txt` to one txt by `cat *ellipse*.txt > annotFile.txt`

***Note you may no need to create it, because `runEvaluate.pl` have do it for you during the running process.***

3.Create FDDB evalute exe, download the source code here [here](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/fddb/evaluation.tgz) 
And then compile it , you may change the makefile, see the reason [here](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/fddb/faq.html), add

```
INCS = -I/usr/local/include/opencv

LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
       -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d 
       -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy
```

to the make file.

4. Evaluate, you can use the `runEvaluate.pl` to evaluate it , but as to me(ubuntu16), I can’t run it directly.

   4.1  change the `GUNPLOT` path(you should install `gnuplot` first using it to create ROC image )

[image]

4.2  I use rectangle detection model, so I change `$detFormat` to 0.

`my $detFormat = 0; # 0: rectangle, 1: ellipse 2: pixels`

4.3  All the images relative path:

```
my $listFile ="/home/xy/face_sample/evaluation/compareROC/FDDB-folds/filePath.txt";
```

4.4  All the images annotations

```
my $annotFile = "/home/xy/face_sample/evaluation/compareROC/FDDB-folds/annotFile.txt";
```

4.5  The roc file you want to generate(created by evaluate exe):

```
my $gpFile ="/home/xy/face_sample/evaluation/compareROC/createROC.p";
```

4.6  You detection file (I will give how to create it latter)

```
my $detFile ="/home/xy/face_sample/evaluation/compareROC/detDir/fddb_rect_ret1.txt";

It’s content like that:
```

[image]

The ‘runEvaluate.pl’ have some error, change the execute evaluation to the below:

```
system($evaluateBin, "-a", $annotFile, "-d", $detFile, "-f", $detFormat, "-i", $imDir, "-l", $listFile, "-r", $detDir, "-z", ".jpg");
```

You can also use command to check it:

[image]

```
xy@xy:~/face_sample/evaluation/compareROC$ ./evaluate \
> -a /home/xy/face_sample/evaluation/compareROC/FDDB-folds/annotFile.txt \
> -d /home/xy/face_sample/evaluation/compareROC/detDir/fddb_rect_ret1.txt \
> -f 0 \
> -i /home/xy/face_sample/evaluation/compareROC/originalPics/ \
> -l /home/xy/face_sample/evaluation/compareROC/FDDB-folds/filePath.txt \
> -r /home/xy/face_sample/evaluation/compareROC/detDir/ \
> -z .jpg
```

Use python to create fddb evaluation txt file:

```
def get_img_relative_path():
    """
    :return: ['2002/08/11/big/img_344', '2002/08/02/big/img_473', ......]
    """
    f_name = 'E:/face_rec/face__det_rec_code/face_det/FDDB-folds/all_img_files.txt'
    lst_name = open(f_name).read().split('\n')

    return lst_name

def write_lines_to_txt(lst):
    # lst = ['line1', 'line2', 'line3']
    f_path = 'fddb_rect_ret.txt'
    with open(f_path, 'w') as fp:

        for line in lst:
            fp.write("%s\n" % line)

# For example use opencv to face detection
def detect_face_lst(img):
    """
    :param img: opencv image 
    :return: face rectangles [[x, y, w, h], ..........]
    """
    m_path = 'D:/opencv/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(m_path)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    return faces


def generate_fddb_ret():
    # The directory from which we get the test images from FDDB
    img_base_dir = 'E:/face_rec/face__det_rec_code/face_det/originalPics/'

    # All the images relative path, like '['2002/08/11/big/img_344', '2002/08/02/big/img_473', ......]'
    lst_img_name = get_img_relative_path()

    # Store detect result, like:
    # ['2002/08/11/big/img_344', '1', '10 10 50 50 1', .............]
    lst_write2_fddb_ret = []

    try:
        for img_name in lst_img_name:
            img_full_name = img_base_dir + img_name + '.jpg'
            img = cv2.imread(img_full_name)

            if img == None:
                print 'error %s not exists, can not generate complete fddb evaluate file' % img_full_name
                return -1

            lst_face_rect = detect_face_lst(img)

            # append img name like '2002/08/11/big/img_344'
            lst_write2_fddb_ret.append(img_name)

            face_num = len(lst_face_rect)
            # append face num, note if no face 0 should be append
            lst_write2_fddb_ret.append(str(face_num))

            if face_num > 0:
                # append each face rectangle x y w h score
                for face_rect in lst_face_rect:
                    # append face rectangle x, y, w, h score
                    # note: opencv hava no confidence so use 1 here
                    s_rect = " ".join(str(item) for item in face_rect) + " 1"
                    lst_write2_fddb_ret.append(s_rect)

    except Exception as e:
        print 'error %s , can not generate complete fddb evaluate file' % e
        return -1

    # Write all the result to txt for FDDB evaluation
    write_lines_to_txt(lst_write2_fddb_ret)
```

After run the above code you can create FDDB result:
[image]

Note: when you create the above txt in windows, if you test it in ubuntu you may get the following error`Incompatible annotation and detection files. See output specifications`:

[image]

Just copy the content to a new txt file(created in ubuntu) then it solves.

Here is the result:

[image]

Some tips:

1. You can see the `runEvaluate.pl` it's not hard, the above changes may not be needed.You can also change some variable in `runEvaluate.pl`, like `$GNUPLOT`, `$imDir` and so on.
   add `"-z", ".jpg"` to
   system($evaluateBin, "-a", $annotFile, "-d", $detFile, "-f", $detFormat, "-i", $imDir, "-l", $listFile, "-r", $detDir);

   system($evaluateBin, "-a", $annotFile, "-d", $detFile, "-f", $detFormat, "-i", $imDir, "-l", $listFile, "-r", $detDir, "-z", ".jpg");
2. You can also read the `evaluate` code(mainly the `evaluate.cpp` which is easy to understand ), so you will have a deep understand of how to evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

can you explain the step you are in?

You need to download the labelled data from: 
http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/fddb/ where it says: **Download the database**

After that you need to download the result source code: 
http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/fddb/results.html

Then you need to modify your program so that the output looks like this:

```
2002/08/11/big/img_591
1
191 88 164 163 0
2002/08/26/big/img_265
3
52 39 95 95 0
282 59 114 114 0
```

Where first is the name of the image,
then the number of faces in that image,
then the coordenates for each face and repeat...

I advice you to build the **evaluation** on linux since it's a lot easier (at least for me it was).

Hope it helps.